# Uniquely identify Messages on multiple inboxes using Graph API/Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I'm building an application for sharing office 365 emails between the users within an organization. I have a problem for uniquely identifying an email which is part of many users' inbox.

In detail, User A sends an email to user B & C, all are within a same organization with a domain abc.com. I tried with Office 365 Graph Mail API and i checked against each users individual mail box where same email appearing with different ids. Is there any way to uniquely identify the email for different inboxes?

When I tried with the Calendar API, there is a property called 'icaluid' which can be used for uniquely identifying the event across shared calendar views. Is there anything like this support for Mail API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the `InternetMessageId` property, which is available in the [Beta version of the Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#message) (make sure "beta" is selected at the top of the page). If you're using Graph, it's on the [v1.0 version of Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message).